# Est-ce qu’il y a un équivalent pour « Sucks to suck! » en français ?

Tags: expressions, traduction

« Sucks to suck! » veut dire que la personne que ça décrit a fait quelque chose de très mal et mérite n’importe quelle conséquence qui suffit.

“I heard he went to prison after killing those people and got beat up there.”

“Oh, well, sucks to suck!”

Est-ce qu’il y a quelque chose comme ça en français ?

Answer (score 3):

Considering [this definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sucks%20to%20suck), I would say an equivalent might be "Dommage !" with irony in the tone of voice. But it seems to be very different from what you explained. Could you please develop your idea or give a few more examples ?

Answer (score 3):

By the exemples found on [urban dictinnary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sucks%20to%20suck) I think you can use something like :

> bien fait pour toi / lui

If you want to mock the person.

If it is just an other way to say "that sucks" I think you can use swears like :

> fait chier
>
> merde

Answer (score 3):

Well litteraly speaking that would be something like

> C'est con d'être con !

That's juste a game of words after all.

But in general, when people talk, they rather use

- C'est ballot !
- Quel dommage !
- Tel est pris qui croyait prendre !

And much more I don't have right now

Comment: +1 for the diversity of registers. "C'est ballot" is very much a current expression - it has become popular in recent years. Dommage, tel est pris..., non. La derniere est un proverbe, et une expression ancienne, pas du tout dans le registre de "sucks to suck".

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce contexte on peux dire :

> Tant mieux pour lui !

Ça veut dire qu'il a mérité ce qui lui arrive.

Comment: Je dirais plutôt « Tant **pis** pour lui ! » dans ce contexte (une mauvaise action)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other (valid) answers, in such a situation, you could also hear some French speakers quote a famous sarcastic [song by Georges Brassens:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rUyfaiZHVQ)

> Quand on est con, on est con.

It can be used if you want to comment a blatant example of a stupid person that won't learn from their mistakes but that you don't feel sorry for them.